# length of paths between two nodes in a directed acyclic graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

What might be a good way to calculate length of all paths between two nodes in a directed acyclic graph? I don't need the actual paths, just the length. Is there a combinatorial formula for that?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for. Do you want to determine the set of possible lengths of paths from one vertex to another?

Comment: suppose a and b are two vertices in a DAG (V,E). There are m paths between A and B. What is the best way to determine length of each of m paths from a to b? I need to do this for all pairs (a,b) that belongs to V.

Comment: This is an easy dynamic programming exercise.  Is it homework?

Comment: That did not occur to me, though it does now. What kind of course would it be an exercise in?

Comment: @Hugh: an algorithms course. The standard algorithm for shortest paths in acyclic digraphs (which is a generalization of most textbook examples of dynamic programming, such as longest common substring) is easily adapted. For $n$ vertices and $m$ edges, it is easy to do it in time $O(mn)$. A lower bound is $n^2$ since that is how large the answer can be, but at the moment I don't see how to do it that fast.

Comment: 1. It's not a home work question, most universities are closed now :-)
2. It's complexity should not be O(n^2), as for each pair of vertices, we can have more than one path, hence, more than one path lengths. The complexity is O(nm). However, I will look into this. Though I was looking for a combinatorial formula, it seems that might not be possible.
3. The matrix multiplication process does it in O(n^4), assuming standard matrix multiplication algorithm.

Comment: When I wrote $O(mn)$ and $O(n^2)$, I must have been thinking about paths from a fixed vertex to each other vertex. Sorry about that. If all pairs of vertices are required, I think $O(n^3)$ output might be needed (unless there is a compressed way of expressing the answer), and $O(n^2m)$ is what dynamic programming does.

Answer (score 2):

Label the vertices from 1 to $n$. Let $A = (a_{ij})$ be the incidence matrix. (The entry $a_{ij}$ is 1 if there is an arrow from vertiex $i$ to vertex $j$ and $a_{ij} = 0$ otherwise.)

Then, the number of paths from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$ of length $k$ is the $a_{ij}$ entry of $A^k$. (This is a well known result that follows from the definitions of matrix multiplication and incidence matrix.)

So, you can determine the (multi-)set of path lengths from $i$ to $j$ by forming each of the $n$ powers and looking at the $a_{ij}$ entry.